# 2D graph animation on WorldWindJava canvas?

Tags: java, animation, graph, jogl, worldwind

Perhaps there are some of you using NASA's worldwind in WWJ form. I just started and set up everything in NetBeans, so that the latest WWJ runs there with jogl and co.
I tested it with basic demo code.

My aim is to display a graph on the WWJ canvas, that will be updated regularly and will be animated in this way. It will be a 2D graph of a dataset, that will be computed in the background and the WWJ programm has to read and display it.

Do you have some tips and EASY examples/tutorials for how I can do that?

Hi, I was able to insert a jfreechart chart, but I haven't been able to "update" the chart yet, could you help me?

```
package screensaver;

import gov.nasa.worldwind.BasicModel;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.avlist.AVKey;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.WorldWindowGLCanvas;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Angle;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Position;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.RenderableLayer;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.Offset;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.ScreenImage;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.Size;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.view.firstperson.BasicFlyView;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.view.firstperson.FlyToFlyViewAnimator;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

///
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class FullScreenTest{

    public static double test = 0;

    /**
     * The animated view
     */
    public static BasicFlyView view;

    /**
     * The ScreenSaver entry point, should run in windowed mode
     * with interactivity or fullscreen mode depending on flags
     * http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/ScreensaverEnhancements
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            view = new BasicFlyView();
        Frame frame = new Frame("WorldwindFull");
        final WorldWindowGLCanvas worldWindowGLCanvas = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
        worldWindowGLCanvas.setModel(new BasicModel());
        worldWindowGLCanvas.setView(view);

        worldWindowGLCanvas.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyListener() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

        RenderableLayer creditsLayer = new RenderableLayer();
        creditsLayer.setName("Credits");
        try {
            creditsLayer.addRenderables(createCredits());
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {

            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
        worldWindowGLCanvas.getModel().getLayers().add(creditsLayer);

                ////
                RenderableLayer chartsLayer = new RenderableLayer();
        chartsLayer.setName("Charts");
        try {
            chartsLayer.addRenderables(createCharts());
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {

            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
        worldWindowGLCanvas.getModel().getLayers().add(chartsLayer);



        frame.add(worldWindowGLCanvas);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        int size = frame.getExtendedState();
        size |= Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
        frame.setExtendedState(size);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        worldWindowGLCanvas.requestFocus();

        setUpTimer();
    }

    /**
     * Static method to produce credits for all involved
     * organisations
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static List<ScreenImage> createCredits() throws IOException
    {
        List<ScreenImage> allCredits = new ArrayList<ScreenImage>();
        ScreenImage creditWWC = new ScreenImage();
        creditWWC.setImageSource(ImageIO.read(
                new File("src/images/worldwindcentral.gif")));
        //TODO: More flexible out of code layout policy
        creditWWC.setScreenOffset(new Offset(0.10, 0.90, AVKey.FRACTION, AVKey.FRACTION));
        creditWWC.setSize(new Size(Size.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO, 0.05,
                AVKey.FRACTION,Size.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO, 0.05,
                AVKey.FRACTION));

                ScreenImage creditRKN = new ScreenImage();
        creditRKN.setImageSource(ImageIO.read(
                new File("src/images/logo_selfnet1.png")));
        //TODO: More flexible out of code layout policy
        creditRKN.setScreenOffset(new Offset(0.50, 0.90, AVKey.FRACTION, AVKey.FRACTION));
        creditRKN.setSize(new Size(Size.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO, 0.05,
                AVKey.FRACTION,Size.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO, 0.05,
                AVKey.FRACTION));

        allCredits.add(creditWWC);
                allCredits.add(creditRKN);
        return allCredits;
    }

        public static List<ScreenImage> createCharts() throws IOException
    {

            // create a dataset...
DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
dataset.setValue("Category 1", 43.2-test);
dataset.setValue("Category 2", 27.9+test);
dataset.setValue("Category 3", 79.5);
// create a chart...
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
"Sample Pie Chart",
dataset,
true, // legend?
true, // tooltips?
false // URLs?
);
//chart.createBufferedImage(100, 100);
// create and display a frame...

//ChartFrame frame1 = new ChartFrame("First", chart);
//frame1.pack();
//frame1.setVisible(true);
//frame1.createImage(100, 100);

final BufferedImage image = chart.createBufferedImage(400, 300);

        List<ScreenImage> allCharts = new ArrayList<ScreenImage>();
        ScreenImage chart1 = new ScreenImage();
        chart1.setImageSource(image);
        //TODO: More flexible out of code layout policy
        chart1.setScreenOffset(new Offset(0.17, 0.60, AVKey.FRACTION, AVKey.FRACTION));
        chart1.setSize(new Size(Size.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO, 0.05,
                AVKey.FRACTION,Size.MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO, 0.05,
                AVKey.FRACTION));

        allCharts.add(chart1);
        return allCharts;
    }

    /**
     * The globe auto-rotate animator
     * @param pos
     */
    public static void moveToLocation(Position pos) {
        if (pos == null) {
            return;
        }
        double elevation = view.getGlobe().getElevation(pos.getLatitude(),
                pos.getLongitude());
        FlyToFlyViewAnimator animator = FlyToFlyViewAnimator.
                createFlyToFlyViewAnimator(view, view.getEyePosition(),
                        new Position(pos.latitude, pos.longitude, elevation),
                        view.getHeading(), view.getHeading(), view.getPitch(),
                        view.getPitch(), view.getEyePosition().getElevation(),
                        view.getEyePosition().getElevation(), 10000, 0);
        view.addAnimator(animator);
        animator.start();
        view.firePropertyChange(AVKey.VIEW, null, view);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience timer set-up to periodically rotate the globe
     */
    public static void setUpTimer()
    {
        int delay = 5000;   // delay for 5 sec.
        int period = 10000;  // repeat every sec.
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    Position pos = new Position(Angle.fromDegrees(
                            180*new Random().nextFloat()-90.0),
                                                Angle.fromDegrees(
                            360*new Random().nextFloat()-180.0),
                                                0.0);
                    moveToLocation(pos);

                            Random rn = new Random();
int n = 10 - 0 + 1;
int i = rn.nextInt() % n;
FullScreenTest.test =  0 + i;
System.out.println(FullScreenTest.test);

                }
            }, delay, period);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to insert a jfreechart chart, but I haven't been able to "update" the chart yet, could you help me?

Comment: See also this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929725) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852).

Answer (score 0):

So you added a renderable layer called creditsLayer which displays an image. A simple (maybe a bit crude) way to update the image is to dispose the layer (`creditsLayer.dispose()`) and re-add it with another image and after `worldWindowGLCanvas.redraw()`. As the screensaver won't update too often this might be acceptable. Or you can have different layers for each image you have and enable/disable them as you need and redraw the canvas. HTH