# JFreeChart XY-chart that refreshes with new set of data? Example?

Tags: java, refresh, charts, jfreechart, redraw

I want to learn how to learn how to create some charts with jfreechart and googlefor some examples. but I couldn't find what I need. This here is good http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/CatalogChart.htm but doesn't have a refreshing graph with new displayed values.

I would like to redraw a chart every nth seconds because I update an external dile witha set of values I want to display here.
So how do I tell jfreechart to refresh the drawn graph and display it onthe canvas?

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series) features a chart that is updated at a selectable rate using an instance of `javax.swing.Timer`.

Addendum: `JFreeChart` follows the Swing [separable-model variation of MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979). `ChartPanel` is a convenient top-level view, as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible). For secular data, a `TimeSeriesCollection` of `TimeSeries` makes a straightforward data model.

Comment: It's almost what I need, thanks! :)
No I just have to understand everything, what it does and have to find out how to put it onto the WorldWindJava canvas.
Perhaps you also have some ideas for achiving this?

Comment: Sorry, I am unfamiliar with `WorldWindJava`, but I've found that `JFreeChart` is fairly easy to integrate; more above.

Comment: Hi trashgod,

I posted the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859286/2d-graph-animation-on-worldwindjava-canvas.
Perhaps you know how I can update the chart regularly.
Andreas

Comment: I've reformatted your [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859286/2d-graph-animation-on-worldwindjava-canvas) and added links in a comment. I've not answered hoping that a `WorldWindJava` user will respond. As noted in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), editing your question (say by adding links) may prove fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this worked for me:

```java
private void refreshChart(){
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.removeAll();
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.revalidate(); // This removes the old chart aChart = createChart();
    aChart.removeLegend();
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(aChart);
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.add(chartPanel);
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.repaint(); // This method makes the new chart appear
}
```