# WorldWind complicated updating 2D interface

Tags: java, bufferedimage, worldwind

I use using WorldWind to plot data, and I also require a 2D interface as an overlay. I have been creating a new BufferedImage a few times per second to update the data, but this requires a lot of overhead. I'd like to redraw on an existing image to decrease the overall usage, both in terms of CPU and memory. I'm using this code before redrawing:

```
BufferedImage img = TrackingService.img.get(width).get(height);
g = img.createGraphics();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
g.fillRect(0,0,img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));
image = img;
```

ach element which can add to the UI returns a HashMap of BufferedImage to Point. Each BufferedImage and point is transformed into a ButtonAnnotation and added to an AnnotationLayer. Each x milliseconds, the system will:

```
layer.removeAllAnnotations();
layer.addAnnotations(buttonAnnotations);
redraw()
```

on the AWT Event queue. This works fine for markers, etc. but these images will never change from the first image I use. I've tried replacing the layer, disposing it, etc. I've tried writing the images to a debug file and noted that the BufferedImage is changing as expected. The problem is that WorldWind must be caching the images at some level. Since I am providing the same instance of BufferedImage to each new ButtonAnnotation, with a few modifications made using Graphics2D, it appears to be assuming that no changes have been made, when, in fact, there have been. This works perfectly fine if I use a new BufferedImage each time I want the data to change.

I have also tried the suggestions in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859286/2d-graph-animation-on-worldwindjava-canvas), and they did not work for me.

Comment: When painting to an image's `Graphichs2D`, always use `try/finally`, and call `g.dispose()` from the `finally` block. As well as releasing native resources, it will also flush any locally cached data to the image. It could help in your case.

Comment: I tried using g.dispose(). No luck.